# VirtualBox не могу создать os удалил файл из virtual medi manager

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox не могу создать os удалил файл из virtual medi manager
[image: снимки экрана]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Нужно найти, остался ли на диске файл vdi - диск виртуальной машины. Там при удалении машины ВБ спрашивает удалить ли и файл. Если есть, то вероятней в папке типа "%User%/AppData/Virtualbox VMs" для виндов. А дальше, в сам менеджер дисков залазить не нужно. В последних версиях ВБ достаточно нажать создать новую машину, и в том окне указать путь к оставшемуся файлу.